# What is the best IDE for Scala?

Tags: ide, scala

I tried programming Scala in Netbeans and Eclipse, but it is not what I'm looking for. In Netbeans suggestions for method names etc. are not working. In Eclipse I can't go to some classes sources by pressing F3. (e.g. scala List).

Is support in IntelliJ IDEA any better? Are there other IDE's supporting Scala?

Answer (score 15):

**IntelliJ IDEA**

Same question has been asked on Stack Overflow. Check out [Which is the best IDE for Scala development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419207/which-is-the-best-ide-for-scala-development)

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain **why**

Comment: IntelliJ is an awsome IDE. While it still shares many problems with Eclipse because it's based on Java technology, it is by far the most reliable of the three I've used. I'm not answering the question thought because I've only used it for Java.

Comment: Has been deleted.

Answer (score 10):

[Emacs ENSIME](http://github.com/aemoncannon/ensime)

Emacs ENSIME is currently the most feature-rich development environment available for Scala.
(Watch [this sneak-peak video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A2Lai8IjLoY) on YouTube.)

Comment: I think ENSIME can also be integrated right in to the sublime text editor for more info refer
[here](http://bit.ly/q3323e)

Comment: Ensime docs seems very linux focussed. Can't really recommend trying it to windows devs.

Answer (score 5):

There's an official plugin for eclipse now.
http://scala-ide.org/
I've tried it myself and it works perfect. Nevertheless all the IDEs here are great. They will probably all do what you want. You should go with the one you feel most comfortable with.